# yum info: what does "Repo: installed" mean?

Tags: rhel, yum, repository, dnf

On RHEL 5 I entered `yum info vsftpd` and got this result:

```
Installed Packages
Name       : vsftpd
Arch       : i386
Version    : 2.0.5
Release    : 28.el5
Size       : 289 k
Repo       : installed
Summary    : vsftpd - Very Secure Ftp Daemon
URL        : http://vsftpd.beasts.org/
License    : GPL
Description: vsftpd ist ein Sehr Sicherer FTP-Daemon. Er wurde komplett von
           : scratch geschieben.
```

But what does `Repo: installed` mean? If I look at `yum repolist` I don't have a repo called *installed*.

Side note: I'm actually trying to find out if vsftpd was installed on the system via yum or without it (i.e. it may was installed manually). Don't know if this is the right way to determine this.

**Update:** to find out the repository one can use `repoquery -i vsftpd` if yum-utils is installed. Found that info [here](https://serverfault.com/a/153314/215126).

Answer (score 4):

`Repo: installed` means: the package is not in a repository, it is installed on the system.

If you use `yum info` with a package name, there are two options:

1. The package is not installed on the system. The top line will read `Available Packages`, and `Repo` will show in which repository the package shown is available.
2. The package is installed on the system. The first line will read `Installed Packages`, and `Repo` will tell you the package is installed.

In the [RedHat Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Displaying_Package_Information.html) yum also shows a line `From repo: [repo name here]`.

Comment: Thank you! With RHEL 5 and Yum 3.2.2 I don't see 'From repo'. I guess that version doesn't contain it. One additional question: my approach to check if the program was installed from a repo is not suitable, right?

Comment: You could check if you can obtain more information via `yum history list vsftpd` to see past yum transactions for vsftpd. Or `rpm -qa --last | grep vsftpd` if it wasn't installed via yum.